# Communicate with the NVIDIA driver after kernel update

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, nvidia, dkms

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I updated my kernel and rebooted and now `nvidia-smi` returns:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

The kernel version is 5.13.0-35-generic.

nvidia-driver is managed by DKMS, which I'm not super familiar with - though I am under the impression that it is meant to stop this kind of problem from happening.

`dkms status` returns:

```
    nvidia, 455.45.01, 5.4.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
    nvidia, 455.45.01, 5.8.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
    nvidia, 455.45.01, 5.8.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
```

So it's looking like there isn't an entry for the current kernel.

So far I've tried to rebuild nvidia-driver with the current kernel by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-driver-455`. This runs, but doesn't change anything (including after rebooting).

I also tried rebuilding all DKMS modules for all installed kernels with `ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools | sudo xargs -n1 /usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start` as suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53364/command-to-rebuild-all-dkms-modules-for-all-installed-kernels. This returns the following error:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch disable_fstack-clash-protection_fcf-protection.patch...patching file Kbuild
Hunk #1 succeeded at 84 (offset 13 lines).


Building module:
cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=5.13.0-35-generic IGNOR
E_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/5.13.0-35-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-455.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-35-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/455.45.01/build/make.log for more information.
Module nvidia/455.45.01 already installed on kernel 5.4.0-58-generic/x86_64
Module nvidia/455.45.01 already installed on kernel 5.8.0-36-generic/x86_64
Module nvidia/455.45.01 already installed on kernel 5.8.0-38-generic/x86_64
```

I think this error might be something to do with the `unset ARCH`, but I'm not sure what that is?

Finally I've tried the switch-it-on-and-off-again equivalent `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-driver-455; sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-455`, which runs, but doesn't solve the problem.

Any help would be amazing - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with the drivers provided by my distribution so I resorted to installing the drivers from nvidia directly, which is a bit cumbersome if secure boot is enabled on your machine. You can read about how to do that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled). I was also facing the issue of the driver not being loaded after kernel updates, so I wrote a script that automatically installs the latest driver, which you can find [here](https://github.com/BdN3504/nvidia-driver-update). In the [read me file of the driver](http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/510.60.02/README/commonproblems.html) it is stated that

> If you upgrade your kernel, then the simplest solution is to reinstall the driver.

Answer (score 0):

i was receving the following error
"NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=4.19.0-20-amd64 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH"
while installing the NVIDIA vGPU Driver on debian 10 with kernel version 4.XXX and i could manage to fix it by do the following :
1-installed proxmox
after doing this the nvidia driver error will change (check for the vfio to be configed)
after that i rebooted the server
2- then i got the error abot the pve headers
so i downloaded .deb header file that was causing the error
3- finally the error fixed for me but now i got stuck to another error :-)
im working on that too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).